# How to model Amazon Redshift external table for changing column structure?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a 5 columns, `c1, c2, c3, c4, c5` in source table (MySQL). I exported the table and added in S3 like:

```
s3://data/table_name/YYYYMMDD/table_nameYYYYMMDDHHMMSS.csv
```

And I exported the data for the 3 months of data.

In later stages, two new columns say `c6` and `c7` added. Now the exported files in `s3://data/table_name/YYYYMMDD/table_nameYYYYMMDDHHMMSS.csv` will have 7 columns

And there is a chance that `c4` column is being removed as well. So the exported files will have 6 columns, i.e. `c1, c2, c3, c5, c6, c7`

How the external table can be modelled to adapt these changes?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you use redshift spectrum / athena you may be OK!

Adding columns - is fine - just run the glue crawler and the new column will be available

deleting columns - is fine - the deleted columns will just appear as nulls

You cannot change a definition of a column.

I definitely recommend - if you can - to convert to parquet and to explore using partitions for your data.

Also, I recommend that you try it out - add the data one change at a time - re-run the glue crawler as necessary - and use athena to make sure all is ok.

Comment: 'Created a sample csv file with 10 rows (street - string, city - string, zip - integer)
Added new columns (state - string, type - string)
Deleted a column (city - string)` I did as you suggested and got the following:
`In the data catalog the deleted column is not removed
While reading the data it skips the deleted column values
After deleting a column from the schema the data from s3 file is as follows:
Removed the column city values
Written the column value zip to the city column
Now the zip column is empty since it is an integer column and the next column is a string`

Comment: any chance you can use parquet? it has many benefits including fixing your issue here

Answer (score 1):

You will need multiple external tables.

Since there is data drift, I think you should create separate tables for each column combinations you have and create a view (with `union all`) on top them to display data.

So you'll have

```
table 1 : columns : c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 
table 2 : columns : c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7
table 3 : columns : c1, c2, c3, c5, c6, c7
```

view as

```
select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, '' c6, '' c7 from table1 union all
select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7 from table2 union all
select c1, c2, c3, '' c4, c5, c6, c7 from table3
```

If there is another combination comes up you need to create a 4th table and update your view definition.